# Can you use pivot_wider to create multiple groups of alternating new columns?

Tags: r, pivot

My data currently looks like this, with the column "Number_Code based on each different Side_Effect:

```
Session_ID   Side_Effect     Number_Code
 1            anxious           1
 1            dizzy             2
 1            relaxed           3
 3            dizzy             2
 7            nauseous          4
 7            anxious           1
```

I know I can do:

```
mutate(rn = str_c('side_effect_', row_number())) %>% 
 pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = Side_Effect)
```

In order to create new column names and put each side effect into a new column like this:

```
 session    Number_Code   side_effect1   side effect_2      side_effect_3    
      1     1                 anxious         NA                 NA
      1     2                 NA              dizzy              NA
      1     3                 NA              NA                 relaxed
      3     2                 dizzy           NA                 NA
      7     4                 nauseous        NA                 NA
      7     1                 NA              anxious            NA
```

But I need to widen the data based on both "Side_Effect" and "Number_Code", and have them in alternating columns like this:

```
 session     side_effect1   number_code1   side effect_2   number_code2   side_effect_3    number_code3
        1       anxious         1              dizzy             2            relaxed          3
        3       dizzy           2               NA               NA           NA              NA
        7       nauseous        4              anxious           1            NA              NA
```

I saw another post where they widened the data based on two variables, but all of the columns for the second one were after all of the columns of the first one. Is there a way to get them to alternate like this? Thank you!!

Comment: There is an open issue regarding this https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/839 . I don't know if a canonical answer exists but most of them would include manipulation of column names/position of some sort.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `pivot_wider` can take multiple `value_from` columns, so after creating the sequence by group, use `pivot_wider` with `values_from` specifying the columns of interest

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(Session_ID) %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = c(Side_Effect, Number_Code))
# A tibble: 3 x 7
#  Session_ID Side_Effect_1 Side_Effect_2 Side_Effect_3 Number_Code_1 Number_Code_2 Number_Code_3
#       <int> <chr>         <chr>         <chr>                 <int>         <int>         <int>
#1          1 anxious       dizzy         relaxed                   1             2             3
#2          3 dizzy         <NA>          <NA>                      2            NA            NA
#3          7 nauseous      anxious       <NA>                      4             1            NA
```

---

If we need to reorder the column order, then we can `select` based on the numeric part and `order`

```
df1 %>% 
    group_by(Session_ID) %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = c(Side_Effect, Number_Code)) %>%
    select(Session_ID, names(.)[-1][order(readr::parse_number(names(.)[-1]))] )
# A tibble: 3 x 7
#  Session_ID Side_Effect_1 Number_Code_1 Side_Effect_2 Number_Code_2 Side_Effect_3 Number_Code_3
#       <int> <chr>                 <int> <chr>                 <int> <chr>                 <int>
#1          1 anxious                   1 dizzy                     2 relaxed                   3
#2          3 dizzy                     2 <NA>                     NA <NA>                     NA
#3          7 nauseous                  4 anxious                   1 <NA>                     NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Session_ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 7L), 
  Side_Effect = c("anxious", 
"dizzy", "relaxed", "dizzy", "nauseous", "anxious"), Number_Code = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: When I do this it organizes the columns like :                                                   side_effect1    side_effect2    side_effect3  number_code1 number_code2 ...                          Is it possible to get it to:                                                                                                          side_effect1  number_code1  side_effect2  number code2 .......

Answer (score 6):

## Edit:

As of `tidyr 1.2.0` this is easily achieved using the `names_vary` argument, where "slowest" gives an alternating order and "fastest" (the default) a block order.

```
# Alternating 

dat |>
  mutate(rn = row_number(), .by = Session_ID) |>
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = rn,
    values_from = c(Side_Effect, Number_Code),
    names_vary = "slowest"
  )

# A tibble: 3 × 7
  Session_ID Side_Effect_1 Number_Code_1 Side_Effect_2 Number_Code_2 Side_Effect_3 Number_Code_3
       <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>
1          1 anxious                   1 dizzy                     2 relaxed                   3
2          3 dizzy                     2 NA                       NA NA                       NA
3          7 nauseous                  4 anxious                   1 NA                       NA

# Block

dat |>
  mutate(rn = row_number(), .by = Session_ID) |>
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = rn,
    values_from = c(Side_Effect, Number_Code),
    names_vary = "fastest"
  )

# A tibble: 3 × 7
  Session_ID Side_Effect_1 Side_Effect_2 Side_Effect_3 Number_Code_1 Number_Code_2 Number_Code_3
       <dbl> <chr>         <chr>         <chr>                 <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1          1 anxious       dizzy         relaxed                   1             2             3
2          3 dizzy         NA            NA                        2            NA            NA
3          7 nauseous      anxious       NA                        4             1            NA
```

First appearance is copied from the order of the `values_from` argument, so if it was desired that `Number_Code` appeared before `Side_Effect` the argument should be `values_from = c(Number_Code, Side_Effect)`.

Comment: Some of the other approaches are shorter, and I might prefer them in practice, but I'm awarding this the bounty because it's the only answer that demonstrates how to accomplish the question's requested operation using only `pivot_wider` and its related functions.

Answer (score 3):

I think the following base R code with `reshape` can help

```
reshape(
  transform(
    df,
    rid = ave(Session_ID, Session_ID, FUN = seq_along)
  ),
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "Session_ID",
  timevar = "rid"
)
```

which gives

```
  Session_ID Side_Effect.1 Number_Code.1 Side_Effect.2 Number_Code.2
1          1       anxious             1         dizzy             2
4          3         dizzy             2          <NA>            NA
5          7      nauseous             4       anxious             1
  Side_Effect.3 Number_Code.3
1       relaxed             3
4          <NA>            NA
5          <NA>            NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible, but `row_number()` is numeric by definition, so I think @akrun's answer is the best approach. Having said that, here is a potential solution for names that are 'both text':

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Session_ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 7L),
  Side_Effect = c("anxious","dizzy","relaxed",
                  "dizzy","nauseous","anxious"),
  Number_Code = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L)
)

df2 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(Session_ID) %>%
  mutate(rn = LETTERS[row_number()]) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = c(Side_Effect, Number_Code)) %>%
  select(Session_ID, names(.)[-c(1)][as.integer(rbind(seq_along(names(.)[-c(1)]), seq_along(names(.)[-c(1)]) + ceiling(length(names(.)[-c(1)])/2)))[seq_along(names(.)[-c(1)])]])
df2
#> # A tibble: 3 × 7
#>   Session_ID Side_Effect_A Number_Code_A Side_Effect_B Number_Code_B
#>        <int> <chr>                 <int> <chr>                 <int>
#> 1          1 anxious                   1 dizzy                     2
#> 2          3 dizzy                     2 <NA>                     NA
#> 3          7 nauseous                  4 anxious                   1
#> # … with 2 more variables: Side_Effect_C <chr>, Number_Code_C <int>


# This can be simplified with a function, e.g.
ordering_func <- function(indices){
  as.integer(rbind(indices, indices + ceiling(length(indices)/2))[indices])
}

df1 %>%
  group_by(Session_ID) %>%
  mutate(rn = LETTERS[row_number()]) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = c(Side_Effect, Number_Code)) %>%
  select(Session_ID, names(.)[-c(1)][ordering_func(seq_along(names(.)[-c(1)]))])
#> # A tibble: 3 × 7
#>   Session_ID Side_Effect_A Number_Code_A Side_Effect_B Number_Code_B Side_Effect_C Number_Code_C
#>        <int> <chr>                 <int> <chr>                 <int> <chr>                 <int>
#> 1          1 anxious                   1 dizzy                     2 relaxed                   3
#> 2          3 dizzy                     2 NA                       NA NA                       NA
#> 3          7 nauseous                  4 anxious                   1 NA                       NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Edit

You can simplify it further using:

```
ordering_func <- function(indices){
  as.integer(rbind(indices, indices + ceiling(length(indices)/2))[indices])
}

df1 %>%
  group_by(Session_ID) %>%
  mutate(rn = LETTERS[row_number()]) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = c(Side_Effect, Number_Code)) %>%
  select(names(.)[ordering_func(seq_along(names(.)))])

#> # A tibble: 3 × 7
#>   Session_ID Number_Code_A Side_Effect_A Number_Code_B Side_Effect_B Number_Code_C Side_Effect_C
#>        <int>         <int> <chr>                 <int> <chr>                 <int> <chr>        
#> 1          1             1 anxious                   2 dizzy                     3 relaxed      
#> 2          3             2 dizzy                    NA NA                       NA NA           
#> 3          7             4 nauseous                  1 anxious                  NA NA
```

(N.B. this approach puts Number_Code_A before Side_Effect_A: this isn't the right order in the original question, but it may not matter depending on the use-case)

Answer (score 2):

Why not do it just based on position?

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Data
d <- structure(list(Session_ID = c(1, 1, 1, 3, 7, 7), Side_Effect = c("anxious", 
"dizzy", "relaxed", "dizzy", "nauseous", "anxious"), Number_Code = c(1, 
2, 3, 2, 4, 1)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    Session_ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Side_Effect = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Number_Code = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 2L), class = "col_spec"))

# Solution
d %>% 
  group_by(Session_ID) %>%
  mutate(rn = LETTERS[row_number()]) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = c(Side_Effect, Number_Code)) %>%
  select(1, as.vector(t(matrix(2:length(.), ncol = 2))))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 7
#>   Session_ID Side_Effect_A Number_Code_A Side_Effect_B Number_Code_B
#>        <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>
#> 1          1 anxious                   1 dizzy                     2
#> 2          3 dizzy                     2 <NA>                     NA
#> 3          7 nauseous                  4 anxious                   1
#> # … with 2 more variables: Side_Effect_C <chr>, Number_Code_C <dbl>
```

This needs adjusting though, if there is more than one ID (2 in the following example):

```r
  select(1:2, as.vector(t(matrix(3:length(.), ncol = 2))))
```

Also, if there are more `values_from` variables, then the `ncol`-argument needs to be adjusted (3 in the following example):

```r
  select(1, as.vector(t(matrix(2:length(.), ncol = 3))))
```